# Parse a text file and write a different file structure

Tags: windows, parsing, batch-file, text-files

I have this database and I need to bring it in a certain structure.
At the moment I have no LinuxOS so I try using Windows Batch only.
The original structure goes somewhat like this:

```
name=Person1
firstname=aaaa
age=00
city=bbbb
country=cccc
telephone=12345678
name=Person2
firstname=dddd
age=00
city=eeee
country=ffff
telephone=11223344
name=Person3
...
```

And now I need to get only certain elements of this structure in a structure like this:

```
name,firstname,telephone
eg.:
Person1,aaaa,12345678
Person2,dddd,11223344
...
```

Since I´m not very familiar with Batch I ended up creating something rather "brute-force" ;)
With my code I come to the point where I get a structure like this:

```
name,firstname,telephone,name,firstname,telephone,name,...
eg.:
Person1,aaaa,12345678,Person2,dddd,11223344,Person2,...
```

And that´s pretty much where I´m stuck right now... my brute-force approach with a lot of IF-conditions doesn´t seem to work... I wonder if I have an error in reasoning, which is very well possible since as I said, I´m not very familiar with Batch.

Ok, sorry, enough talking. Please take a look at my blunt and ugly code:

```
@echo off
set count=1
type testfile.txt | findstr /V age | findstr /V city | findstr /V country >> work.txt
For /F "usebackq tokens=2 delims==" %%A in ("work.txt") Do @<nul set /p"=%%A,">>"work2.txt"
For /F "tokens=* delims=," %%A in (work2.txt) DO (
IF %count% EQU 1 (set name=%%A)
IF %count% EQU 2 (set fname=%%A)
IF %count% EQU 3 (set phone=%%A, set count=0)
set /a count+=1
) %name%,%fname%,%phone%>> done.txt
del work.txt, work2.txt
exit
```

Anyone willing to help? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set "telephone="
(for /F "delims=" %%a in (testfile.txt) do (
   rem Set variable with value of current line
   set "%%a"
   if defined telephone (
      echo !name!,!firstname!,!telephone!
      set "telephone="
   )
)) > done.txt
```

Comment: +1 That's very clever - it just needs the header line written too.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION 
SET "separator=,"
SET "F1="

FOR /f "tokens=1*delims==" %%a IN (q25597324.txt) DO (
 IF NOT DEFINED F1 (SET "F1=%%a"&CALL :zapflds)
 IF /i "%%a"=="!F1!" IF DEFINED $%%a CALL :report %*
 SET "$%%a=%%b"
)

CALL :report %*

GOTO :EOF

::
:: Report fields required
::
:report
IF "%1"=="" ECHO %$$:~1%&GOTO zapflds
SET "$$=%$$%%separator%"
FOR  /F "tokens=1*delims==" %%m In ('set $%1 2^>Nul') DO IF /i "%%m"=="$%1" SET "$$=%$$%%%n"
SHIFT
GOTO report

::
:: Clear fields-being-used
::
:zapflds
:: remove variables starting $
FOR  /F "delims==" %%z In ('set $ 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%z="
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q25597324.txt` containing your data for my testing.

Simply run *thisbatchname* name,firstname,telephone

to produce the repor of the fields required in the order required.

The routine works by setting `f1` to the name of the first field encountered (I assumed that the next occurrence of that fieldname would indicate a new record.) That field name is recorded and all environment variables that start with `$` are cleared.

Then each fieldvalue is assigned to a variable `$fieldname` until the next occurrence of `f1`. When `f1` next appears as a fieldname, a report line is generated and the `$` variables are cleared again.

The very last record is reported upon, since there is no `f1` after the last field.

The parameter to the `:report` routine is simply the list of required fields from the command-line. The string `$$` is built with a separator and the content of the first nominated field, that fieldname removed from the list by the `shift` and continue until there are no required-fieldnames left. Then show the value built in `$$` (except the first character), clear up after ourselves and all done!

Answer (score 0):

This solves the task as stated:

`file.txt` is the input file and the output file is `file.csv`

```
@echo off
set "file=file.csv"
set "terms=name firstname telephone"
>"%file%" echo %terms: =,%
for /f "tokens=1,* delims==" %%a in ('findstr /i "%terms%" ^< "file.txt" ') do (
   if /i "%%a"=="telephone" (set /p =%%b<nul&echo() else (set /p =%%b,<nul)
) >> "%file%" 
pause
```